# Best approach on single and multiple deletion in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I got a overview page where I can click a button to delete a single row or can selected multiple rows to be deleted.

Because laravel can only delete an item by sending it as a delete request, I am curious what's the best approach on this issue.

I really don't want to use ajax for this because I'm leveraging feedback messages etc with Session::flash.

It would be really great to do something like: `item/1?action=destroy` for the single row, so I can use a form for the multiple values to be deleted, because I can't nest a form for the single row.

I would love to hear your way of doing these things.

Comment: perhaps you don't understand what ajax is, but calling that destroy URL, without reloading the page, is ajax.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't see `without reloading the page` in my question, because I want to reload the page ;). I dont want to use AJAX because it does the delete without a page refresh and with  AJAX I can't leverage the benefits of laravel as well.

Comment: actually with ajax you can check the result of the destroy first. Success? excellent: straight up call `window.location = http://thepageineed;` and off you go to the page with updated data models. A bit silly given modern browsers and the history API, but perfectly fine. But on error you can be far more intelligent about things

Comment: I didn't know I'm able to use return a session after the page reload from my success function. Works great now.

Answer (score 1):

Your page can have just a single form, and include `submit` buttons (or `input`s with `type="submit"`) alongside each row, with `name="delete"` and `value` set to the ID of the row. In addition, you can have a checkbox next to each row, again with `value` set to its ID, and then one "Delete Checked Rows" submit button with `name="deleteMultiple"`. This form would `POST` to a route that would take a look at the `Input` values, and act accordingly:

- If a single row's delete button was clicked, `Input::get('delete')` will
  contain the ID of the single row to be deleted, which you can pass to
  your `destroy` method.
- If the "Delete Checked Rows" was clicked,
  `Input::has('deleteMultiple')` would return true, and the  `Input` would
  have contain array of which checkboxes were checked. You can then do
  something like `Item::destroy(array(1, 2, 3));`.

You can use javascript to streamline or enhance some of the form handling, though it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

public function destroy(Request $request)
    {

```
    $sd = $request::get('id');
    if (!empty($sd)) {
        $register = Register::findOrFail($sd);
        $register->delete();
    } else {
        $data = $request::get('chk');

        foreach ($data as $d) {
            $register = Register::findOrFail($d);
            $register->delete();
        }
    }


    return redirect('register');
}
```